# SQL query for converting column values in row dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, distinct, unpivot

I am new to SQL so don't know much if you can help me out for eliminating duplicates from my query 1 or help me to transpose query 2

Old query 1: I already tried below query but some duplicate values were returned:

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(case when TransactionType = 1 then 1 else null end) desc) AS 'td','',
    Warehouse as 'td','',
    Createdate as 'td','',
    count(case when TransactionType = 1 then 1 else null end) as 'td','',
    count(case when TransactionType = 5 then 1 else null end) as 'td','',
    count(case when TransactionType = 6 then 1 else null end) as 'td','',    
    cast(round(sum(localamount),8) as decimal(18,2))as 'td',''
from
    PaymentTrn (nolock) 
where 
    CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1,112) as int) 
group by 
    Warehouse, CreateDate
order by 
    count(case when TransactionType = 1 then 1 else null end) desc
```

Then I tried count(distinct case when TransactionType = 1 then 1 else null end) but is giving only 1.

For query 2 (shown here next),  have 3 (useful) columns in DB invoice-type, transaction-type and warehouse from which I need to fetch data.

**IMPORTANT**: invoice number  has duplicates so I need to use distinct

because I am getting duplicate values I modify the query, now I need to convert "no column name " column to row

Current output for a query is:

```
warehouse    no column name
1700             3
1700             6
1700             9
```

query 2:

```
select warehouse,count(distinct(invoicenumber))
from PaymentTrn (nolock)
where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and TransactionType = 1
group by Warehouse,CreateDate

union all

select warehouse,count(distinct(invoicenumber))
from PaymentTrn (nolock)
where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and TransactionType = 5
group by Warehouse,CreateDate

union all

select warehouse,count(distinct(invoicenumber))
from PaymentTrn (nolock)
where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and TransactionType = 6
group by Warehouse,CreateDate
```

the expected result should need to be:

```
warehouse    transactiontype=1       transactiontype=5       transactiontype=6
1700              3                      6                       9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want conditional aggregation with `count(distinct)`.  You seem to want to count invoice numbers:

```
select row_number() over (order by count(distinct case when TransactionType = 1 then invoicenumber end) desc) AS td, '',
       Warehouse as td, '',
       Createdate as td, '',
       count(distinct case when TransactionType = 1 then invoicenumber end) as td, '',
       count(distinct case when TransactionType = 5 then invoicenumber end) as td, '',
       count(distinct case when TransactionType = 6 then invoicenumber end) as td, '',    
       cast(round(sum(localamount), 8) as decimal(18,2)) as td, ''
from PaymentTrn 
where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1, 112) as int) 
group by Warehouse, CreateDate
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your queries.

**Query 1:**

```
select t2.rownum as 'td',''
    , t1.Warehouse as 'td',''
    , t1.Createdate as 'td',''
    , t2.cnt as 'td',''
    , t3.cnt as 'td',''
    , t4.cnt as 'td',''
    , cast(round(sum(t1.localamount),8) as decimal(18,2))as 'td',''
from 
PaymentTrn t1
left join
    (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(1) desc) as rownum, Warehouse
    from
        PaymentTrn (nolock) 
    where TransactionType = 1 and CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1,112) as int) 
    group by Warehouse) t2 on t2.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
left join
    (select count(1) as cnt, Warehouse
    from
        PaymentTrn (nolock) 
    where TransactionType = 5 and CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1,112) as int) 
    group by Warehouse) t3 on t3.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
left join
    (select count(1) as cnt, Warehouse
    from
        PaymentTrn (nolock) 
    where TransactionType = 6 and CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1,112) as int) 
    group by Warehouse) t4 on t4.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
where 
    t1.CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -1,112) as int) 
order by t2.rownum desc
```

**Query 2:**

```
select t1.warehouse, count(distinct(t1.invoicenumber)) as TType1, t2.cnt as TType2, t3.cnt as TType3
from PaymentTrn  t1
left join
    (select Warehouse, count(distinct(invoicenumber)) as cnt from PaymentTrn 
     where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and TransactionType = 1 group by customer_code) t2
    on t2.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
left join
    (select Warehouse, count(distinct(invoicenumber)) as cnt from PaymentTrn 
     where CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and TransactionType = 1 group by customer_code) t3
    on t3.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
where t1.CreateDate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate() -305,112) as int) and t1.TransactionType = 1
group by t1.Warehouse, t2.TType2, t3.TType3
```

Comment: yes it worked... but can you please help me in query 1 for same results as I used count(distinct(case statement for transectiontype)) there but it didn't worked. it is giving results as all 1's in that column there

Comment: it is giving same results....the thing is I want to use distinct to eliminate duplicate results in count(case when TransactionType = 1 then 1 else null end) as 'td','',

Comment: can we do using just a distinct keyword in query 1 and get results without using joins.

Comment: the query 2 data is giving result for only 30 warehouses...but it needs to give for 61 warehouse stores